# How to switch view modes of Insta360 One X in VCL

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have some Insta360 One X footage in the camera's native INSV format and am using VLC 3.0.8 Vetinari. VLC is able to play the footage back, but it displays it in the mode where there's a frustrum from the camera out and you have to drag your mouse around to point it around the sphere to change what you're looking at. Supposedly, it supports the planet view as well, according to the some articles I read online, although they refer to "VLC 360" which might have been a fork of VLC? Can't find anything about it now.

Does VLC 3.0.8 support multiple view modes for 360 footage and if yes, how does one switch them?

Comment: VLC 360 is what you're using, the Venitari branch. I can't answer the question because I don't have any 360º footage :)

Comment: I thought it was a "temporary" binary made from the Venitari branch which was released as a preview of this feature before the branch was merged to the main stable VLC branch, did not realized it was a nickname for it. Thank you. In any case, now that it _is_ merged, hopefully it was merged with all the supposed features, like the different modes, not only the basic playback part of it. I looked everywhere in the UI but didn't find any controls. I looked for example footage online, but didn't find anything downloadable unfortunately.